# Launch Web Application on Google Cloud App Engine or Compute Engine VM Instance Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm not so sure if I should be asking this question on StackOverflow but I don't know where else to ask.

I want to launch my coded Website programmed through pure `JavaScript` and `PHP`. I wish to save as much money as I can on this website and I want to choose the CHEAPEST Service. So can someone advise me on using `Google Cloud Compute Engine VM Instance (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)` or either `Google Cloud App Engine` to save money. If I will be using the `Google Cloud Compute Engine VM Instance (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)`, I will not be using any other Cloud Service, I will be using the inbuilt `Apache MySql and Server`. If I will be using the `Google Cloud App Engine`, I will be using `Google Cloud SQL` and `Google Cloud Storage`.

So which Service would be cheaper to launch my website? Also are there other similar services available? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that it's a bit difficult to answer your question and a bit out of scope for Stack Overflow. It depends on various factors (how many instances you will need if you will use App Engine, what memory, CPUs etc.) The best thing to do is use the [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) that Google Cloud provides to calculate the cost based on your needs and decide.

Comment: What will be the best amount of instances, memory and CPUs to use for the cheapest service?

Comment: This heavily depends on what your website does, how much traffic you expect and stuff like that. If it's a simple website with low traffic, then maybe it's a good idea to publish it on the App Engine but again, this depends on many factors

Comment: My website will be streaming multiple`YouTube iframe` video and the website will be retrieving number of `MySQL` rows as the User Scrolls the page. So which service will be cheaper to run this on?

Comment: Sorry but I honestly can't answer the question (that's why I haven't added my comments as an answer too). As I said it depends on a lot of stuff and it's primarily opinion based.